# Растянуть блок на всю высоту экрана (body)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу растянуть контейнер на всю высоту `body`.

Нужно, чтобы главный контейнер с классом `.template` растягивался на всю высоту `body`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.template {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="template template-index"></div>
```

Comment: `height: 100%`?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Простой способ растянуть блок на всю высоту:

`height: 100vh;`

Есть много способов растянуть блок на всю высоту, однако самый простой и изящный способ — применить единицу измерения `vh`.

```
section {
    height: 100vh; /* высота секции равна высоте области просмотра */
}
```

Comment: лучше будет если Вы добавите особенности единицы измерения vh ...